# Modifying Mac OS terminal colours does not work. Possibly due to bash_profile modifications of anaconda?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, anaconda

I am on Mac OS. There are all sorts of tutorials to modify the terminal font with colours, etc., to make it more readable. I followed [this one here](https://osxdaily.com/2013/02/05/improve-terminal-appearance-mac-os-x/) in trying to enable colours for the `ls` command, but I failed. I copy pasted the extra lines into the `.bash_profile`, but it did not have an effect, even after closing and opening terminal again.

First of all: Is there an easier way, other than modifying the .bash_profile? For example, in the terminal preferences I checked the hook at `Display ANSI-colors`, but it did not seem to have an effect either.

If not, then: This is just a suspicion, but I suspect it might have something to do with my anaconda installation, which added some lines to the `.bash_profile`. (Another user experiencing a similar issue has posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58494860/anaconda-installation-modifying-bash-profile-on-mac-os-x).) Since my anaconda installation my temrinal prompt also looks a bit different:

```
(base) <username>@macbook ~ %
```

It has now that `(base)` added in front, and I think the ending `~ %` was also different before.

Anyway, the content of my .bash_profile (without the extra lines for colouring the `ls` output) is:

```
# added by Anaconda3 2019.10 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
# . "/Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"  # commented out by conda initialize
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

I am unfortunately not well read enough in bash to realise what is going on here

Answer (score 0):

you can try to follow this:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apple-mac-osx-terminal-color-ls-output-option/

instead of using .bash_profile, or similar, try to change the

~/.zshrc

Greetings!